# MDX Measure Customer by Category count optimizing

Tags: performance, ssas, mdx, bigdata

Here is my measure :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[ContactNumber]  AS 
nonempty(   
    UNORDER(
        (UNORDER([Contact].[Contact Id].[Contact Id].MEMBERS)   
        ,{linkmember([Period].[Per Quarter].currentmember,[Period Ending].[Per Quarter]).NextMember : STRTOMEMBER('TAIL([Period Ending].[Per Quarter].[' + [Period].[Per Quarter].currentmember.LEVEL.name +'],1)(0)')}
        ,{NULL :[Period].[Per Quarter].currentmember}       
        ,[Category].[Category].currentmember)
    )
,[MAX_BeginDate]
).count
```

it gives me how much customers there are in a category at a period

my fact table is liked

```
contact periodin periodout category
A       25       26        cat1
A       26       27        cat2
A       27       end       cat3
B       1        26        cat0
B       26       end       cat1
C       1        2         cat2
C       3        4         cat2
C       4        end       cat3
```

And my dimensions :

```
Period            regular by periodin 
Period ending     regular by periodout 
contact           regular by contact 
category          regular by category
```

So for the 26th, I will have :

```
cat0       0
cat1       1(B)
cat2       1(A)
cat3       1(C)
```

If someone think to an obvious improvement...
it tooks me over 1min-1min30 for all 4categories in one day of 2017. There are more than 100 million rows in the table fact. Every customer has at least 1fact. Calendar begins in 2000 and there are 60 million of customers.

Thank you

Regards
Antho

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is faster:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[ContactNumber]  AS 
 SUM(
   UNORDER(
        (UNORDER([Contact].[Contact Id].[Contact Id].MEMBERS)   
        ,{linkmember([Period].[Per Quarter].currentmember,[Period Ending].[Per Quarter]).NextMember : STRTOMEMBER('TAIL([Period Ending].[Per Quarter].[' + [Period].[Per Quarter].currentmember.LEVEL.name +'],1)(0)')}
        ,{NULL :[Period].[Per Quarter].currentmember}       
        ,[Category].[Category].currentmember)
    ), 
   IIF(
      ISEMPTY([MAX_BeginDate])
     ,NULL
     ,1
   )
)
```

I think `linkmember` is a slow function - is there any alternative you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering,

I beleive I already tried replacing the count function by sum without good results.
But as soon as I go back to work I will try your proposition.

Yes I can replace all linkmember by reconstructing every member with level, current member name and strtomember function. It is something I can also try.

I also have the period of customer entry. I use it to know if the customer is "new" at the current period. And maybe it could be possible not browsing all the period dimension from the begining but from the "in period" of the customer...